# In terms of usability, what is the best way to export a file?

Tags: android, file, usability

I have an android app which allows the user to gather research data. I want to export the gathered data as an excel file. So the user can work with the data on a desktop computer.

The question is, what is the best way in terms of usability to offer file export to the user?

On idea was to start the email client with the excel file as attachment. But if you have to send this email to yourself just to get the files seem kind of a workaround.

The second idea is to store the file in the android file system. But is there a commen folder for something like that? Like the "Documents" folder in windows? I dont want the user to search too long for his file. And is this really best practice?

Comment: this question is primarily opinion-based ... I would use share/view/send action(with FileProvider) - so user would decide what to do with shared content ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common way, is using the shared intent system and allowing the user to pick which app "he" or "she" wants to use to share the file. You can also save it to the android file system just as easily. There is no common folder which everyone should use. But if you want ease of accessibility for the file, create a new sub-directory under the top-level directory on the device. Use this method to get a reference to the top-level, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(). You must have the android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission declared in your app Manifest. The sub-directory name should be something obvious to that user that the data inside belongs to your app. Furthermore, display a toast that indicates to the user where the file is stored to make it even easier for them.